# Getting VBA Excel to break at point of crash

Tags: vba, excel

It used to be that my EXCEL VBA program would break right at the point where the code crashed.

It no longer does that.

So for example, I would have a routine like this where I launch my program from:

```
Sub workBook_open()
    
    Call Open_Workbook
    
End Sub
```

To actually run the program, I put cursor the Sub Somewhere and hit the Play button triangle |>

The program crashes somewhere, but I am not placed on the line that crashes.

I just see my error message, but I am not automatically put on THE line of code that caused the crash.

It used to not behave this way.

How do I get the old behavior back to where it will crash on THE line of code that caused the crash?

The only thing I really did since the behavior change was to split my code up into modules.  Whereas before, I had lots of code in 2 different modules, I split it up....

Comment: Sounds like one of the settings for on error has been changed

Comment: VBE, choose Options from the Tools menu, and click the General

Comment: QHarr, yes, that has  a great option to break on all errors... if you post as a reply instead of comment, I will accept that as an answer!

Comment: Added. Also put a link to some best practices and info about the other options.

Comment: Export all your modules and then re-import to clean them.

Comment: @SMeaden Is there any info on that option? I have heard it mentioned before but have no idea why/how it would work.

Comment: @QHarr - VBA's internal storage of the code can build up (for want of a better word) cruft.  Exporting and re-importing gives a fresh clean copy.

Comment: So same problem as Excel in general which seems to hoover up metadata etc.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `Break On All Errors` is selected from VBE > Options > Tools > General

Other settings are described [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-handling-errors-in-vba/).